# What does 'recent phone numbers' mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

## **In addition to displaying recent phone numbers**, the new IF20 mobile phone shows the temperature, the  time, and the user's location on a map.

At first I've just thought that 'phone numbers'(전화번호) means just numbers which I can call literally, but translation says that 'phone numbers' in this sentence means 'call log'(통화 기록).

So I was wondering if 'phone numbers' can mean 'call log' in certain context.

thank you in advance!

Comment: *In that context* **recent phone numbers** would be understood to mean "phone numbers this phone has been in contact with recently" or "Call Log". Of course you're not in contact with the number, but with the device the number has been assigned to, and indeed not with the device either, but with some communicator using the device, either a person or an automated messaging machine of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context it seems call log only because phone numbers is followed by **recent**. In general it is not the case.